# How is an ASP.NET read by the browser?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, html

How does the browser interpret an `ASP.NET` webpage, hosted in `IIS`?

The first time the webpage is accessed, is something installed in the browser? Or `ASP.NET` creates "normal" `HTML` pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS interprets and executes the ASP.NET code and markup and sends HTML to the browser.

The browser interprets the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

ASP .NET is server side. It executes remotely and delivers standard HTML page to browser

Answer (score 1):

> "An ASP.NET page has the extension .aspx. If a browser requests an
>   ASP.NET page, the server processes any executable code in the page,
>   before the result is sent back to the browser."

Quoted from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_pages.asp) website.

Answer (score 1):

The first time the asp.net page is accessed it is compiled into a .net class (together with the code behind). There is a so called ISAPI filter installed into iis. When you access an asp.net page (a file with .aspx extension) iis will use the ISAPI filter to execute the request using class that has been compiled.

Answer (score -1):

everything you need is [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms972976.aspx) my friend

Comment: That article is more specifically about viewstate, which is not what he is trying to understand.